# In AngularJS, any inline javascript code that included in HTML templates doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In AngularJS, any inline javascript code that included in HTML templates doesn't work.

For Example:

main.html file:

```
<div ng-include="'/templates/script.html'"></div>
```

And script.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('yes');
</script>
```

When I open main page, I expect an alert message that say 'yes' but nothing happens. I think some security restrictions in the AngularJS is preventing inline scripts, but I couldn't find any workaround about that.

Note: I don't use jQuery or any other framework, only AngularJS 1.2.7.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

jQlite does not support script tags.  jQuery does, so the recommendation is to include jQuery if you need this functionality.

From Angular's Igor Minar in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/H4haaMePJU0/discussion):

> we looked into supporting script tags in jqlite, but what needs to be
>   done to get a cross-browser support involves a lot of black magic. For
>   this reason we decided that for now we are just going to recommend
>   that users use jquery along with angular in this particular case. It
>   doesn't make sense for us to rewrite one third of jquery to get this
>   working in jqlite.

Here's the related github issue [jqLite should create elements in same way as jQuery](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/369) where Igor sums up, before closing the issue, with this:

> This is too much craziness for jqlite, so we are not going to do it.
>   Instead we are going to document that if you want have script elements
>   in ng:include or ng:view templates, you should use jquery.

[demo plunker with jquery](http://plnkr.co/edit/asl07QNUU4MUClUZnOJm?p=preview)

Comment: I loaded jQuery, and now the `alert` works. But controllers are not working. Do you know why?

Comment: jQuery is already included before Angular in my code and it still does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @molerat same here but it works if this jquery version is added before angular - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 6):

Angular uses the $sanitize on `ng-include` directives which strips out scripts.  A better approach for templates is to create a controller for that template.

It is better to use an individual controller for templates.

In template.html

```
<form role="form" ng-controller="LoginController">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="login()">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

In the `LoginController` you can use whatever code you want

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('LoginController', [function() {
      alert('controller initialized');
  }])
```

Comment: Do you know a workaround to disable that sanitizing?

Comment: I was researching it but nothing jumped out at me. There seem to be ways to bypass the sanitize process if you are using it via js, but I couldn't find a way to specifically make the directive itself ignore sanitizing.

Answer (score 3):

The event triggered when `ng-include` adds content is `$includeContentLoaded`. Your scripts should be included in this event:

For example ([Plucker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3SSczrhpZwM318V4aLsD?p=preview)):

```
function SettingsController($scope, $window) {
  $scope.template={};
  $scope.template.url = "demo.html";

  $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event){
    $window.alert('content load');
  });

}
```

Additionally you can set an init function using the `onload` attribute:

**html**

<div ng-include="template.url" onload="alertMe()"  > </div>
 </div>

**Controller**

```
$scope.alertMe=function(){
    $window.alert('sending alert on load');
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Include jQuery and change order of the `angular.js` and `jquery.js`. jQuery must be first, otherwise it does not work