# Javascript in ionic template can't working

Tags: ionic-framework

I have no idea why the script tag can't working, here is the reproduce step:
ionic cli 1.3.10

1.ionic start mytab

2.add following to templates/chat-detail.htm in `ion-content`

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var txt="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt.length;
</script>
```

3.ionic serve --lab

4.navigate to chat detail page,the script couldn't work

why is that happened?

Comment: What are the errors in the browser's console? Also, can you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Comment: there is no error in the browser's console, jsfiddle doesn't have ionic framework?

Comment: You can include external libraries in jsfiddle. Try this Ionic starter template: http://jsfiddle.net/Chofoteddy/y7D4r/

Comment: The angularjs template doesn't support <script> tag, refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336350/angularjs-inline-script-in-the-included-html-template

Answer (score 0):

try put the js to the controllers, something like:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.loaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt.length;
}
```