# angularjs routing, javascript does not work on injected views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I just followed the tutorial on the link below
https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

I did exactly as is described on the page, but evoluting it to a real project, I had to put some javascript code inside internal pages, pages/about.html for example. and for some reason, it is not executed. even you put a single

```
<script>
    alert('foo');
</script>
```

it's not interpreted as a javascript code. and the alert is not shown

pages are injected using ng-view

```
<div id="main">

    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

whole code can be viewed in 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

thanks

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336350/angularjs-inline-script-in-the-included-html-template

Comment: My guess would be the html is being inserted with innerHTML, which doesn't execute javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/rc4yv1Lq/1/

Comment: it's really easy to put code into directives. Will find it a much simpler path if you are just starting out

Answer (score 0):

I´ve been using scripts inside my templates (for lazy loading) for some time now without knowing that **AngularJS** wasn't doing the entire work. However, you can acomplish the task if you combine **AngularJS** with **JQuery**.

Check the following snippet for a solution:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>angular app</h1>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
        template: '<a href="#script">i´m feeling lucky!</a>'
      })

      .when('/script', {
        templateUrl: 'script.html'
      });

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**script.html**

```
script successfully loaded!
<script>alert('ok');</script>
```

The import order is important in this case. If you swap the **JQuery** with the **AngularJS** the solution will not work.

Hope it helps!