# AngularJS routing load script on template load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my single page application inside one of route templates I have script which loads (in place where it is placed) some content, like inputs and some forms.

simple example hot it looks:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-md-12 centered-col-div" style="height:300px">
     <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.getContent.com' ></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I put this code in main page, it works perfectly, but inside route template it is not executing. maybe someone can help me and say how to execute this code when route template is visible.

Comment: Possible reason - you'll have to include jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336350/angularjs-inline-script-in-the-included-html-template

Comment: It's working fine for me http://plnkr.co/edit/hTnLokvMfmDwCpMDo5uZ?p=preview can you try isolating the issue in a separate plunker ?

Comment: I was a little bit, wrong, Script is loaded, but all contend which this script provides is placed in bottom of page. How to place it in the same place, where the script is.