# Javascript ads in Angular templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ads, angular-template

I'm trying to render a Javascript ad in my Angular template but it will not show up. I've found some solutions when they append the Javascript to the head tag but I want the ad to be placed in my Html (inside body).

Here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/WHhQ95gS5HKSphmmirio

Here is a simple plain Html example that works.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="ad">
       <script src="http://media.affiliatelounge.com/data/nordicbet/ad_js/display_88.js?ad=ad_793270_88.html&amp;size=300x250&amp;clicktag=http://record.affiliatelounge.com/_sVuSoFFh4LK58VwA2IUESrKVVrME-Gsw/1&amp;media=108786&amp;campaign=1"></script>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But if I add the div inside an Angular template it will not render and the console says nothing.

I have some ads up and running here (http://www.odds.nu/erbjudanden), but they are either .gif or iframes. I want to be able to show Javascript ads instead. They are added to the Html but are not rendered (placed in the bottom of the page).

Can $sce or $compile help somehow?

My index.html

```
    <div data-ng-view="" class="mainView"></div>
```

My app.js

```
    $routeProvider.when("/erbjudanden", {
          controller: "offerController",
          templateUrl: "/app/templates/offers.html"
    });
```

My offers.html

```
    <div class="ad">
       <script src="http://media.affiliatelounge.com/data/nordicbet/ad_js/display_88.js?ad=ad_793270_88.html&amp;size=300x250&amp;clicktag=http://record.affiliatelounge.com/_sVuSoFFh4LK58VwA2IUESrKVVrME-Gsw/1&amp;media=108786&amp;campaign=1"></script>
    </div>
```

Any solution?

Comment: What does that script do?

Comment: @Voreny It loads an "image" with a link basically. Didn't post the correct source since it's irrelevant.

Comment: the source code of the script is completely relevant

Comment: Aah, is it? Sorry! Here is the script 

<script src="http://media.affiliatelounge.com/data/nordicbet/ad_js/display_88.js?ad=ad_793270_88.html&amp;size=300x250&amp;clicktag=http://record.affiliatelounge.com/_sVuSoFFh4LK58VwA2IUESrKVVrME-Gsw/1&amp;media=108786&amp;campaign=1"></script>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had inspected result of that url request(make sure adBlock is off)

```
https://wlbetclic.adsrv.eacdn.com/S.ashx?btag=a_17172b_14837c_&affid=12824&siteid=17172&adid=14837&c=
```

You will see the actual result

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//wlbetclic.eacdn.com/TrafficOpt/s.5.4.min.js?t=1"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//wlbetclic.eacdn.com/wlbetclic/img/js/Affiliate_12824.js?t=20160224"></script>');
//other lines omitted for brevity
```

So this file is executing `document.write` which obviously will not work in angular, just because they are totally different (even though you could trigger digest cycle somehow, you still don't have access to modify that script file, as it's generated by 3rd party server and has own variables)

What i would do is - make a page like ad.html, just like index.html or 404.html, then request this file from angular (not as template, but like a view file) as an iframe src with custom attributes

And i would use custom DOM element, and populate contents with jQuery, or with angular, look at jQuery sample below

Also i would need [krux/postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe) plugin, because [you cannot use document.write in async html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297829/execute-write-on-doc-it-isnt-possible-to-write-into-a-document-from-an-asynchr)

```
<!-- create multiple holders -->
<ad-holder url="https://wlbetclic.adsrv.eacdn.com/S.ashx?btag=a_17172b_14837c_&affid=12824&siteid=17172&adid=14837&c="></ad-holder>

<div class="black-widow">
    <!-- with size attributes -->
    <ad-holder url="http://google.com" width="100" height="40"></ad-holder>
</div>

<!-- jQuery population with iframe -->
<script>
    //get all custom elements
    $('ad-holder').each(function(){

        //create iframe placeholder
        var $iframe = $(document.createElement('iframe'));

        //get url of custom element
        var url = $(this).attr('url');

        //request ad.html file with params, currently it's url param
        $iframe.attr('src', 'ad.html?url=' + url);

        //some stylings acceptable here
        $iframe.width('100px');

        //or get styles from custom-element
        var heightValue = $(this).attr('height');
        $iframe.height(heightValue || '50px');

        //rebuild custom element with iframe
        $(this).append($iframe);
    });
</script>

<!-- angular populate with iframe directive -->
<scrip>
    angular.module('app', []).directive('adHolder', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { url: '@' },
            //you could also execute in compile-phase
            link: function(scope, element, attribute){
                var $iframe = angular.element(document.createElement('iframe'));
                $iframe.attr('src', 'ad.html?url=' + scope.url);
                element.html($iframe);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And **ad.html** would look like

```
<body>
  <div id="ad"></div>
  <script>
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      //for the sake of simplicity we expect only 1 param (url)
      return query.replace('url=', '');
    }
    var adUrl = getQueryVariable('url');
    if (adUrl) 
      postscribe('#ad', '<script src="' + adUrl + '"><\/script>');
    else {
      var $h1 = $(document.createElement('h1'));
      $h1.text('No ad available');
      $(document.body).append($h1);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

The best part of this solution is that you can reuse same custom-element with different `url` attribute for any other ads

[Checkout jQuery real working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/j04oE3AS8A7UYdBRq6wp?p=preview)

Although this demo heavily uses jQuery, it's easy to tweak for angular version, which i would suggest you to implement as homework =)

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. I haven't tried it yet but I guess you deserve the bounty anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Angular does not perform compilation of Javascript in HTML templates. You either put the HTML manually in the page (instead of loading as template) or have another way to call it.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336350/angularjs-inline-script-in-the-included-html-template)

Comment: What do you mean by "manually in the page"? In my index file?

Comment: And I also have Jquery loaded before Angular, still doesn't render.

Comment: If you put a script tag in an angular html template, it will not compile: ergo, it will not run. Don't put script tags in templates

Comment: Well, I'm open for alternatives. Any ideas except "don't do this"?

Comment: Why does it has to be in a template and not in the raw html element?

Comment: What do you mean by raw html element? It's not a template as in a directive template or a separate template that I use with ng-template. It is one of my "main views". 

Do you have an example?