# Are controllers mandatory for writing directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm just a beginner in angular JS. I'm learning to a write a directive.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"/>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.directive('helloWorld',function()
{
return{
restrict: 'AEC',
replace: 'true',
template: '<h1>helloWorld</h1>' 
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World example</h1>
<hello-world></hello-world>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, what is wrong in the above code, I get an error - **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]**.
1. Is controller mandatory to write a directive, does it not inherit from $rootscope.
2. How can I master directives.

Comment: What's the error?  I think that generally the template needs to be a textual representation of an element -- Not a text node.  Does it work if you change the template to `'<div>helloWorld</div>'`?

Comment: @mgilson Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Can you please try replacing "angular.min.js" in the script tag with "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js" and see if it is working in your local?

Comment: @NitinGarg Link isn't working

Comment: please add http:// before ajax.google...

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a controller, but your template needs to be actual html, since you have set `replace: true` in your directive. You can either fix that:

```
template: '<h1>helloWorld</h1>'
```

...or take out `replace: true`, and your directive works. See [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true) on what's happening with `replace`.

[See this plunker adapted from your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/gAFKm2RDJbDylC2AdTA1?p=preview).

There are a ton of great resources online to learn about directives, but the best one I have found is [this Udemy course by Dan Wahlin](https://www.udemy.com/angularjs-custom-directives/learn/). It's worth the price, especially if you catch the reduced-rate offers. He also wrote [an excellent series of blog posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals) that mirrors the Udemy course and illuminates the key concepts.

Comment: Well though I change that, I still get the module error. I don't think that can be areason for the error.

Comment: local env. benett. Angular is loading fine.

Comment: Updated the plunk. You cannot use inline script tags unless you also [include a reference to jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336350/angularjs-inline-script-in-the-included-html-template). You can either pull the app declaration and directive into a separate script and refer to that, or add the jquery script.