# Execute Javascript that's inside a blog from a database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several blogs that are stored in my database. Some of them have javascript calculators inside the html like this one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.financialsoccer.com/FinancialSoccer.js"></script>
```

I cannot get angular to parse the html and run the javascript.

So when it comes from the DB, it gets put into the scope value and looks something like this

```
$scope.article= '<h2> Financial Soccer</h2><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.financialsoccer.com/FinancialSoccer.js"></script>'
```

I am already running it through $compile to compile any directives that may be in the blogs but the javascript wont execute.

```
.directive('dynamicElement', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                article: "="
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var template = $compile(scope.article)(scope);
                element.replaceWith(template);
            }
        }
    }])
```

Is there a way to make this happen? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336350/in-angularjs-any-inline-javascript-code-that-included-in-html-templates-doesnt

Comment: Yea, that doesn't really help. I already have the full version of jquery on the page. Thanks

Comment: Of course it helps...it explains what you need to do. You can't run those tags through `$compile` and will need use jquery to insert the html.

Comment: I also need to run it through compile to attach directives in the html.

Comment: then you need to figure out another approach to including your scripts such as `$.getScript()`. There are serious security concerns allowing scripts in content the way you are doing which is one main reason angular strips them