# <script> not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code inside the view(partial) of AngularJS

```
<%@ page 
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<p>
some text
</p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ alert("WORKS");  }) 
</script>
```

I need it here and not in controller as later I want to implement Google Map.
However the alert is not triggered. What may be the reason?

Relative part in the output HTML

```
    <div id="partials">
    <!-- ngView: --><div data-ng-view="" class="ng-scope">

<p class="ng-scope">
text

</p>

<script type="text/javascript" class="ng-scope">
    $(function(){ alert("WORKS"); });


        </script></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you remembered to include jQuery? AngularJS only supports jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped.

Comment: yes even if I think it is not necessary. (even without $(document) it is not working

Comment: do you get any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: no, no errors at all

Comment: Can you post the generated html that you see in the browser? Maybe it just doesn't get generated due to caching issues

Comment: You can't have script tags in angular templates. Do it some other way.

Comment: @Brian Script tags can be in Angular templates, but JQuery must be included and override JQLite - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340885/4951118

Comment: in fact I do include jquery
   <script src="./resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/jquery-ui.min.css" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Library must stand before AngularJS library in declaration. This has solved my problem